Yasmarang prng, recover internal state
Some Casio calculators use MicroPython, which uses Yasmarang as the prng. The seed is 32 bits, so the state can be brute forced, assuming that the 4 consecutive outputs were created immediately after seed initialization.
I've figured out a method to recover the internal state given 4 consecutive outputs, regardless of the number of times it's been called after seed initialization, using no more than $2^{40}$ guesses. I have 2 questions.

Given 4 consecutive outputs, is there a more efficient method than brute force?
If more than 4 consecutive outputs are available, does it simplify or speed up the process of recovering the internal state vs brute-force methods?

Below is a copy of the Yasmarang definition. Seed initialization sets the variable pad to the value of the provided seed. In the absence of a specified seed, pad is initialized to the default value 0xeda4baba. The other variables—n, d, and dat—are initialized to fixed default values (n = 69, d = 233, and dat = 0) and are not influenced by the seed.
unsigned long yasmarang(void)
{
static unsigned long pad = 0xeda4babaL, n = 69, d = 233;
static unsigned char dat = 0;

pad += dat + d * n;
pad = (pad<<3) + (pad>>29);
n = pad | 2;
d ^= (pad<<31) + (pad>>1);
dat ^= (char) pad ^ (d>>8) ^ 1; /* changed, see update below (1) */

return (pad^(d<<5)^(pad>>18)^(dat<<1));  /* changed, see update below (2) */
}  /* yasmarang */


Here are the test vectors using the default seed for the first 20 outputs.
BF5B0806 7334585E BC0C7B9D BDEC5ADE A5F12D68
978CA203 8CE2E203 37B2CE15 1B986BD2 2F3F1111
40197A2D 31057AB0 579401A4 1CF95A3C 744882AD
E6179123 9E1CAC6A 0D77D709 FB34195F 77831C40

